# How to get Jenkins build result in email notification

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have a jenkins job, and in that job, I have html format email notification. I need build status/result variable. I tried `{ENV,var="BUILD_RESULT"}`, but it doesn't work.

Could someone help me how to get build result information and print out in the email notification?

Answer (score 1):

When using some of the pre-built templates I was using the following to get the state of the build and the last 250 lines of build-output:

```xml
<b style="font-size: 200%;">BUILD ${build.result}</b>

<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
<div class="content">
  <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/console">
    <h1>Console Output</h1>
  </a>
  <table class="console">
    <j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(250)}">
    <tr>
        <td><tt>${line}</tt></td>
    </tr>
    </j:forEach>
  </table>
  <br />
</div>
```

See the following places for more examples/templates:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-TemplateExamples
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates

Comment: May I have just build result parameter? I'm afraid I don't have privilege to add template on jenkins server